# Android libraries performing facebook login, complications

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

We are developing an Android Application and a SDK(android-library) for it. The SDK will be integrated into other partner applications. We want to use Facebook as our login provider across both the app and the sdk.

Our understanding/plan is that the partners will now need to integrate their app with facebook(create the app on developers.facebook.com and etc) and then we will be able to use the facebook SDK in our SDK, but with their applicationid. We then send the token over to the server to access the `/me` api to get the facebook ID which we then use as a login ID into our system.

1. If we(via sdk) call fb session open and the host application has already
   authenticated to fb, will we be getting the same token?
2. Are there any legal or other issues regarding this? Is this a privacy issue?

   1. With facebook?
   2. With host application developers?
   3. Is there a way to handle this purely with terms and conditions style stuff?
3. Can we somehow request a fresh access token with just the permissions we need? Would this solve this issue?

We were initially considering if we would be able to have a seperate application id for our SDK, but that wouldnt work because facebook requires us to associate a keyhash with the application....

Are there any other instances like these of libraries using facebook login? This sounds like this should be impossible somehow... otherwise all ad libraries just need to integrate with FB sdk to get all the access they want.. 
I also came across [this recent news article, which sounds similar, but not sure if it is](http://www.symantec.com/connect/blogs/facebook-applications-accidentally-leaking-access-third-parties-updated)

Edit: Seems like facebook IDs are application specific now.. bummer - http://code-worrier.com/blog/changes-in-facebook-graph-api-2-dot-0/

Comment: i think you can put multiple keyhash in your single app in facebook developer account.

Comment: @HareshChhelana yeah that was what was occuring to me when i was typing it out, so one keyhash per partner.. would that work/fix issues?